# trapizium divs with mouse events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I want to have a div structure like this.

```
______________________________________
|          \                          |
|           \                         |
|            \                        |
|  Div A      \      Div B            |
|              \                      |
|               \                     |
|________________\____________________|
```

This can be done by css styling using border properties. But using border properties, transparent border remains on the top of the other, so I can not track the mouse click/hover event properly. That is, if z-index of `Div A` is greater than `Div B` and a mouse click event happens on `trans of A`, then the click is registered to happen on `Div A`, not on `Div B`. But I want it to happen on `Div B`.

```
______________________________________
|        |\ trans|                    |
|        | \ of A|                    |
|        |  \    |                    |
|  Div A |   \   |   Div B            |
|        |    \  |                    |
|        |trans\ |                    |
|________|_of_B_\|____________________|
```

Any help using CSS or Javascript or jQuery ?

Comment: Maybe you could use SVG instead like they did similar here with clipping images as triangles: http://jsfiddle.net/xTd6Y/4/ - I do not think you can achieve this with CSS to my knowledge: when you hover the trapezoid you basically have a square with a transparent area. http://jsfiddle.net/EJD6e/4/

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

Comment: Have you tried wrapping Div A and Div B in another div (Div C)?  You can trap the mouse click event on Div C and use the x/y coordinates of the call to determine whether to call DivA/DivB function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W2DQ8/3/) using css3 transforms...

```
.skewed.box{
    -moz-transform: skewX(20deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg);
    -o-transform: skewX(20deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(20deg);
    transform: skewX(20deg);
}
```

Hover the divs to see the event follows the shape. I quickNdirty'd the rest of the CSS, but you get the idea...

Oh, and note that the content of the skewed div is skewed in the opposite direction to make it appear, well, not skewed.